# AWS Cognito with Reactjs App error during signup call - Start of structure or map found where not expected

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have made a React app and trying to integrate AWS cognito for User signup and Sign in. I am getting error when submit button is pressed -"Start of structure or map found where not expected.".
[image]

Comment: What are you using to connect to Cognito? You may find that using [AWS Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication) will make your life easier.

Comment: I am using AWS Amlify only.

Comment: Please post the ReactJS code you have implemented for authorization.

Comment: Should be malformed data; Do you make a call in Amplify similar to this
Auth.signUp({
      username: username, 
      password: password,
      attributes: {
         email: 'lokendra.....'
         phone_number: '+917...',
         gender: 'male'
      }
   });

Comment: Thanks, Solved. I was using wrong format.